# Visual Studio 2012 undocumented warning C4447

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, warnings

```
dllmain.cpp(16): warning C4447: 'main' signature found without threading mode
l. Consider using 'int main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ args)'.
```

Above is a warning I got from building a Windows Store App DLL project. I didn't change anything in that default dllmain.cpp file except for including my own version of pch.

The documentation for this warning (along with many VS2012 errors/warnings) is nowhere to be found on MSDN and here is the only relevant link I can find:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/6daa9587-fe54-4e84-a8b9-0e5c52c2f6e8/

and the op there didn't get an answer.

If anyone knows what it means and how to fix it, it would be great!

Comment: Consider building dllmain.cpp without the `/ZW` flag.

Comment: Thanks summits. That's a good answer. If you would like to make it as an answer, I can vote it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can safely ignore the warning. The compiler cribs when it sees a Win32-style `DllMain` being compiled using the `/ZW` flag (*Consume Windows Runtime Extensions*). However, the function gets called as you'd normally expect.

Alternatively, you can work around the warning by compiling `dllmain.cpp` without `/ZW`. You might need to adjust the PCH settings for this to properly work. This is the path taken by the *DLL (Windows Store apps)* C++/CX project template in Visual Studio.

Incidentally, the reason you do not get the warning when you're trying to build a *Windows Runtime Component* project (which builds everything using `/ZW`) is that a Windows Runtime Component doesn't declare a `DllMain`. This is not to say that it can't; it just picks up the dummy `DllMain` that the CRT defines (which basically turns off per-thread initialization and reports success).